# How does delete_at(n) work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

If I create a new array with 10 elements, and populate it with the numbers 1 through 10, then call `delete_at(4)`, the fourth element is "deleted".

How does this work, though? Does it completely remove the element and index and reduce the size of the array to 9, or does it nullify (or make nil) the value of that index and push it the the end of the array?

Comment: You could 1) read the documentation or 2) try it. (If you're asking about the *implementation*, not the semantics, be sure to draw out the topic.)

Comment: I meant how the mechanics of the method work, and the documentation's single sentence didn't explain that.

Comment: The [documentation (and example)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) explains the semantics just fine. Make sure to word questions (which can also be updated) such that they focus in on the precise issue/problem.

Comment: Might I ask why the downvotes, for future reference? I believe I worded it fine.

Comment: I down-voted for being rude to the documentation, which contains a clear example :|

Comment: Rude to the documentation? I do not believe it is in the guidelines to downvote for this reason.

Comment: It was unclear to my purpose, in my perception. That is a matter of opinion; not a valid reason to downvote. Could you please revoke it?

Comment: Very well, since it means so much. (Remember that documentation was created by someone, and even meager documentation can sufficiently answer a question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It copies all of the elements after the position back one with a single memory copy, then reduces the size of the array by one.

Why do you ask? Are you trying to reason about performance?

Ref: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/9f45081627cf682b3ee938353da134d6f28560da/array.c#L2964

Comment: I see. Thanks for answering; the documentation's one sentence didn't quite cut it.

Comment: The documentation has a nice example that accompanies the one sentence. Reviewing that example, then playing with it in IRB if necessary, would have immediately showed how it worked, that a nil element was not added to the end of the array. Beyond that, digging into the source code would have showed in detail the mechanics of the method.